# Calculo de tiempos a intervalos php

Tags: php, mysql, date, horas

Tengo la siguiente base de datos como se ve en la imagen, necesito calcular con php que tiempo se encuentra libre y que tiempo en completo, extraer estos datos mediante un array y analizar el mismo en php, lo que quisiera es una sugerencia como hacerlo, porque no me sirve el sumar los tiempos de COMPLETO o LIBRE, ya que seria información errónea.
[image: Base de Datos]

Como se aprecia en la base de datos hay horas en que esta el Libre, pero después se pone en completo, necesito poder calcular los minutos que esta en LIBRE y los que esta en COMPLETO. Este es el funcionamiento de un parking que comienza las 9 de la mañana y así por 12 horas.

Lo he intentado solucionar de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php 
      
      //variable hora y minutos
      $hora_inicial = "09:00:00"; 
      $min_libre = 0;
      $min_compl = 0;
      
      //Recorro el array que contiene los datos
      foreach($obtener_estados as $data):

       //Obtengo la hora de la tabla   
       $hora_actual = $data['hora'];

      //Obtengo el estado de la tabla
       $estado = $data['estado']; 
       
       //Si el estado es LIBRE
       if ($estado=='LIBRE'){
           $start = strtotime($hora_inicial);
           $end = strtotime($hora_actual);
           $minutos = ($end - $start) / 60;
           $min_libre += $minutos;
           $hora_inicial = $hora_actual;
       } 
       
       //Si el estado es LIBRE
       if ($estado=='COMPLETO'){
           $start = strtotime($hora_inicial);
           $end = strtotime($hora_actual);
           $minutos = ($end - $start) / 60;
           $min_compl += $minutos; 
           $hora_inicial = $hora_actual;
       }
       
      endforeach;
   ?>
      <tr>
        <td>LIBRE</td>  
        <td><?= $min_libre; ?></td> 
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>COMPLETO</td>  
        <td><?= $min_compl; ?></td> 
      </tr>
```

Los tiempos que me da están mal calculados

Saludos a todos y Gracias por anticipado

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136071/discussion-on-question-by-elyera-calculo-de-tiempos-a-intervalos-php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mi propuesta para tu caso, en PHP, es la siguiente:

```
$obtener_estados = [
    ["estado" => "LIBRE", "hora" => "09:01:54"],
    ["estado" => "LIBRE", "hora" => "09:05:54"],
    ["estado" => "COMPLETO", "hora" => "09:06:24"],
    ["estado" => "COMPLETO", "hora" => "09:06:54"],
    ["estado" => "LIBRE", "hora" => "09:07:24"],
    ["estado" => "LIBRE", "hora" => "09:08:54"],
    ["estado" => "COMPLETO", "hora" => "09:09:24"],
    ["estado" => "LIBRE", "hora" => "09:09:54"],
];

//variable hora y minutos
$hora_inicial = "09:00:00"; 
$seg['LIBRE'] = [];
$seg['COMPLETO'] = [];

foreach($obtener_estados as $data) {
    $seg[$data['estado']][] = strtotime($data['hora']) - strtotime($hora_inicial);
    $hora_inicial = $data['hora'];
}

function formatear_segundos($seg, $tipo) {
    $suma_seg = array_sum($seg[$tipo]);
    $horas = intdiv($suma_seg, 3600);
    $minutos = intdiv(fmod($suma_seg, 3600), 60);
    $segundos = fmod(fmod($suma_seg, 3600), 60);    

    return $horas." horas, ".$minutos." minutos, ".$segundos." segundos";
}

?>
<tr>
<td>LIBRE</td>  
<td><div><?= formatear_segundos($seg, 'LIBRE'); ?></div><pre><?=print_r($seg['LIBRE'], true);?></pre></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>COMPLETO</td>  
<td><div><?= formatear_segundos($seg, 'COMPLETO'); ?></div><pre><?=print_r($seg['COMPLETO'], true);?></pre></td> 
</tr>
```

En este ejemplo el resultado es:

```
LIBRE
0 horas, 8 minutos, 24 segundos

Array
(
    [0] => 114
    [1] => 240
    [2] => 30
    [3] => 90
    [4] => 30
)

COMPLETO
0 horas, 1 minutos, 30 segundos

Array
(
    [0] => 30
    [1] => 30
    [2] => 30
)
```

### Explicación detallada

- Primero inicializamos un par de arrays con las claves **LIBRE** y **COMPLETO**, dentro del array $seg que de este modo pasa a ser multidimensional.

```
$seg['LIBRE'] = [];
$seg['COMPLETO'] = [];
```

- Despues recorremos el array multidimensional origen de los datos, **$obtener_estados**, mediante un bucle [foreach()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php) de este modo:

```
foreach($obtener_estados as $data) {
```

- Donde en cada ciclo vamos a evaluar el tipo de estado recibido en **$data**, calculando el número de segundos entre la hora del anterior ciclo (o inicial) y la actual, y agregarlo a su correspondiente array *$seg[tipo]*, de este modo:

```
    $seg[$data['estado']][] = strtotime($data['hora']) - strtotime($hora_inicial);
```

**Nota:** Para que funcione bien los datos de *$obtener_estados* deben estar ordenados por fecha

- Una vez agregado el dato en su array correspondiente vamos a reasignar la variable **$hora_inicial** por la hora recibida en el ciclo, pues lo necesitaremos para calcular los segundos del siguiente ciclo correctamente:

```
    $hora_inicial = $data['hora'];
```

- Y finalmente creamos una función denominada `formatear_segundos($seg, $tipo)` que recibe dos parámetros correspondientes al array **$seg** y al **$tipo** deseado. Dicha función formateará los segundos en un formato de horas, minutos y segundos. Las funciones que usamos en el son [array_sum()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-sum.php) para calcular la suma de segundos del tipo parametrizado, [intdiv()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.intdiv.php) y [fmod()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.fmod), que nos ayudan a dividir los segundos en horas y minutos.

Comment: Ahora mismo lo pruebo y te digo

Comment: Lo primero que quiero hacer es agradecer a todos los que han contestado, soy todos muy grandes porque en un día he podido solucionar el problema, @masterguru tu solución perfecta ya que esta muy limpio con respecto al que realice anteriormente, que descubrí que el error que tenia era que al obtener el array no lo organizaba por la hora, al hacerlo nos da el mismo resultado pero tu solución me gusta mucho mas que la mía. Muchísimas gracias. las de mysql muy buenas soluciones tambien, he aprendido un montón en un día con todos, muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro que te haya funcionado. Ya he agregado la explicación pendiente para que la respuesta esté mejor documentada. Saludos!!

Comment: Perfecto ahora si que ha quedado super explicado para que un futuro le pueda servir a cualquiera que lo necesite, muy bien @masterguru . Saludos

Answer (score 3):

Una forma de resolverlo con MySql >= 8.0 (se que lo estás intentando resolver con php, pero quizas a alguien mas le sirve esta solución).

Entiendo que el turno del parking es de 9 hs a 21 hs. Según los comentarios, para cada fila calculas el tiempo transcurrido entre dicha fila y la posterior, pero según tu cógido php lo haces al revés (entre la fila anterior y la actual). Yo lo voy a hacer el cálculo entre la fila actual y la posterior. Para la última fila (como no hay otra fila para realizar el cálculo) lo calculo con la hora final del turno (21 hs). Ten en cuenta que no estoy contemplando el tiempo transcurrido entre las 9 hs y el primer registro del día (ya que no se  si está libre u ocupado, porque no esta dicha información), pero se podría tener en cuenta.

Lo que hago primero (subquery sq) es utilizar la función de ventana `lead` para calcular el tiempo transcurrido entre la fila actual y la siguiente (para todas las filas). Luego en la query principal agrupo por fecha y estado, y sumo los intervalos calculados.

```
WITH sq AS (SELECT *,
                   SUBTIME(COALESCE(lead(hora) OVER (PARTITION BY fecha ORDER BY hora ASC), '21:00'), hora) AS intervalo
            FROM parking)

SELECT fecha,
       estado,
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(intervalo))) AS tiempo
FROM sq
GROUP BY fecha, estado;
```

Salida (con datos de ejemplo propios):

Para cada fecha mostará el total de horas, minutos y segundo (lo puedes expresar en minutos o segundos si así lo quieres) de cada estado (libre/completo).

| fecha | estado | tiempo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-08 | LIBRE | 11:54:39 |
| 2022-04-08 | COMPLETO | 00:03:27 |

Answer (score 2):

Puedes obtener con SQL los minutos ocupados agrupando por hora-minuto:

```
SELECT count(1) mins_ocupado
  FROM ( SELECT fecha
              , hour(hora) hr
              , minute(hora) min
              , min(estado) edo
           FROM nose
           GROUP BY fecha
                  , hr
                  , min
           HAVING edo = 'COMPLETO'
       ) m;
```

Con la función de agregación `min()` se establece el criterio de conteo:
En un minuto hay dos lecturas con intervalo de 30 segundos, si por lo menos en una lectura esta ocupado, se toma todo el minuto como ocupado. Usamos el mínimo dado que la C de completo va antes que la L de libre.

Los minutos libres los obtienes restando los minutos ocupados a 720 minutos (12 horas).